# Looping over EncryptedDataBagItems starting from a specific index or without a specific object in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I currently have a databag which contains some secret configs. Everytime a new config is made, it will be added to the databag as seen below:

```
{
    "id": "config-databag",
    "config1": {
        "name": "config1",
        "secret": "supersecretpassword"
    },
    "config2": {
        "name": "config2",
        "secret": "supersecretpassword"
    }
}
```

In my recipe, I retrieve the databag and have a template which will render all the configurations into a file using a partial template:

```
secret_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret('/path/to/data_bag_key');
configurations = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load('my-databag', 'config-databag', secret_key).to_hash

template 'file' do
    source 'file.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '644'
    variables(
        'configurations' => configurations
    )
    notifies :restart, 'service[foo]'
end
```

file.erb

```
<% @configurations.each do |config| %>
<%= render 'append-config.erb', :variables => { :name => config[name], :secret => config[secret] } %>
<% end %>
```

append-config.erb

```
special config <%= @name %> : <%= @secret %>
```

Is there a way where I can loop over all the data items in the databag except for the "id" object? I am currently using version 11.8.2 of Chef on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use each_pair iterator, you can skip `id` by using `next` or you can delete it before passing to variables (`delete_if` method).

```
hash = {
    "id" => "config-databag",
    "config1" => {
        "name" => "config1",
        "secret" => "supersecretpassword"
    },
    "config2" => {
        "name" => "config2",
        "secret" => "supersecretpassword"
    }
}
```

And now it can go two ways.

```
hash.each_pair do |key, value|
  next if key == "id"
  puts key
  puts value["name"]
  puts value["secret"]
end
```

or

```
hash.delete_if { |key, _| key == "id" }
hash.each_pair do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value["name"]
  puts value["secret"]
end
```

Comment: This is much nicer than me having an if statement checking to see if the value was a String. Thanks very much.